# CSS :hover tag not working? display: none to inline-block

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a nav menu for a website...
I'm using the css :hover function change the `display` tag from `none` to `inline-block`.

I've done this many times before with absolutely no problems. Now however it does not seem to work.

This is my code in its simplest form:
When the `.parent` div element is hovered over, the `.child` div element is supposed to appear.

Anyone know why it's not doing that?

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
}
.child {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
}
.parent:hover .child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div class="parent">Parent</div>
</a>
<a href="">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Child isn't inside parent, so the rules don't match

Comment: `.child` is not a child of `.parent`. Your selector suggests that `.child` is _inside_ `.parent`

Comment: `.parent:hover .child` looks for an element with the class `child` that is a descendant of an element with the class `parent`. Since there's no parent or ancestor selector in CSS, based on your HTML you can't do what you want with only CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this)

```
<a href="">
  <div class="parent">Parent</div>
</a>
<a href="">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</a>

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
}
.child {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
}
a:hover + a .child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

live - https://jsfiddle.net/d26L7juy/

Answer (score 0):

Put the child into the parent - a link is not necessary for hover to work:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
}
.child {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
}
.parent:hover .child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">Parent
  <a href="">
    <div class="child">Child</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your child div was not inside the parent Div

```
  <div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="" class="parent">
  <div>Parent</div>
</a>
<a href="" class="child">
  <div>Child</div>
</a>

.parent:hover + .child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```